# Azure web app - create ssl binding?

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I have 4 web apps in azure. I had a certificate that was being used for the ssl bindings and I just uploaded a new one, deleted the bindings which were using the old certificate, and removed the old certificate.

Now I'm trying to add bindings using the new certificate, and I keep getting "failed" messages. No real explanation or descriptions, just failed.

How do you add a new binding? I've tried in both the new and the old portal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I found a better description of the error:

The certificate with thumbprint 'FSDGFSDFFDSGFSD3423EDSEF43ERGWE' is invalid for SSL. The Enhanced Key Usage must be present and must contain Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1).

Comment: what was the fix? I'm getting this error now, unsure how to move forward

Comment: Crap. I don't even remember.

Answer (score 0):

Most CA's will add the extensions:

```
X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
 TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
```

You can check a running certificate with:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep -A 1 'X509v3 Extended Key Usage'
```

In my situation the pfx file was malformed. Keyvault would accept it no problem, but Azure WebService would fail to update the binding.

Fix is to re-generate pfx file.